# Odd ColdFusion Behavior--Abort Not Honored

Tags: coldfusion

Using ColdFusion 9.01, occasionally, we have observed an issue where an error may be occurring within a CFC function and when we attempt to add writeDump(foo); and abort; calls to debug the error ColdFusion does not honor those calls.

Example:

```
private void function index(Event)
{
    var rc = Event.getCollection();
    var prc = Event.getCollection(private=true);

    /** NOT HONORED! **/
    writeDump(var=rc);
    abort;

    prc.JSON = {};
    prc.JSON.show = variables.APIProxy.call(
         handler = 'shows'
        ,action = 'read'
        ,event = arguments.Event
        /** THE ERROR IS OCCURING HERE **/
        ,params = { language=lcase(rc.language.getLanguage_Medium()), show=rc.show_name }
    );
    prc.JSON.showEpisodes = variables.APIProxy.call(
         handler = 'episodes'
        ,action = 'index'
        ,event = arguments.Event
        ,params = { language=lcase(rc.language.getLanguage_Medium()), show=rc.show_name, detail=true }
    );
    prc.JSON.products = variables.APIProxy.call(
         handler = 'products'
        ,action = 'index'
        ,event = arguments.Event
        ,params = { language=lcase(rc.language.getLanguage_Medium()), detail=true }
    );
    Event.addAssets(
        'model/product.js
        ,model/show.js
        ,collection/product_mobile.js
        ,collection/show_mobile.js
        ,view/product_mobile.js
        ,view/productList.js
        ,view/show_mobile.js
        ,view/showList.js
        ,model/episode.js
        ,view/episode_mobile.js
        ,view/episodeList.js
        ,collection/episode_mobile.js
        ,collection/product_mobile.js
        ,mobile/episodeObject.css
        ,mobile/show.js
        ,mobile/show.css
        ,mobile/category.css
    ');

    Event.setLayout('layout.mobile');
    Event.setView("show/index_mobile");

    return;
}
```

I believe we have successfully eliminated caching. I am curious if anyone else has encountered this.

Thank you.

Aaron

Comment: Have you tried `writeDump(var=rc, abort=true);` as a matter of interest?

Comment: You sure it's not caching?  can you make other changes below the abort and see if the func is really not cached?

Comment: Yes to both. Even restarts of CF wont help. Template caching is also disabled. Very odd. First observed a few months ago and happened again today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was with the struct literals declared within the argument calls to a function.

Comment: Sounds like a parser error, as user349433 guessed. Have you reported this on the Adobe cfbugs tracker? (There's no reason struct literals shouldn't be valid in an argument call.)

Comment: Please vote up this bug: http://cfbugs.adobe.com/cfbugreport/flexbugui/cfbugtracker/main.html#bugId=82955

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing that the error is a *parse* error, not a true runtime error, so it gets thrown *before* the function actually executes. It's not actually skipping over your `abort`, it just fails to parse (or execute) the entire thing.

I'm not sure why you're getting a parse error there, but I do know the CF code that handles struct literals is somewhat flaky.

Answer (score 0):

i'm going to go out on a limb here and say that your issue might have something to do with this bug:

http://cfbugs.adobe.com/cfbugreport/flexbugui/cfbugtracker/main.html#bugId=86960

is there anything in your app that executes in the onRequestEnd() method?

it would be helpful to tell us what exactly is happening and/or the output you're getting when the issue happens.